# using DotSpatial plugins in my app

Tags: plugins, dotspatial

I am new with dotspatial and I want to enable and use plugins on my own. I have a custom button that I want to add, it's a click handle measure function and shows the results in a text label.

Is there a way to use the measure plugin in this case? How can I use it ?

I just need some hints and if it is possible a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sample](http://mudnug.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/how-to-support-loading-extensions-in-dotspatial/) demonstrates how to load plugins (extensions) such as the measure plugin in your own app. You may need to implement IHeaderControl to get the full UI experience as demonstrated at 
http://mudnug.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/how-to-load-dotspatial-extensions-into-my-toolbar/

Comment: Thanks man,I wanted to use them with my custom button actions.I managed to do that by editing extentions..Thanks